# Unexpected identifier in /location while compiling ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I keep getting these "Unexpected identifier in /location/ while compiling ejs" Not sure what the solution is here, I've tried to use the different opening tags but when I use the "<%-" tag I get an unidentified if statement error message

```
<% if (kindOfDay === "Saturday || kindOfDay === "Sunday") { %>
  <h1 style="color: blue"> <%=kindOfDay%> To Do List</h1>
<% } else { %>
  <h1 style="color: green"> <%=kindOfDay%> To Do List</h1>
<% } %>
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting makes it clear you didn't put a closing quote after Saturday

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe that's all it was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the closing quotation mark for the first condition.
Try this one,

```
<% if (kindOfDay === "Saturday" || kindOfDay === "Sunday") { %>
  <h1 style="color: blue"> <%=kindOfDay%> To Do List</h1>
<% } else { %>
  <h1 style="color: green"> <%=kindOfDay%> To Do List</h1>
<% } %>
```